# howto, Use JQUERY .EACH() but not for a element, for a Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, each

In Javascript,  I have a variable that is set to a block of text from a WYSIWYG editor.

I want to use JQUERY's EACH() to find span's with the class XXXX.

```
$( "span.foods" ).each( function() {});
```

But I want it to search in the variable=lookhere I have since I don't have access the the text in the WYSIWYG editor directly (CKEDITOR).

How can this be done?

Comment: Could you be more clear on what you want?  You have an array of elements you want to search through, or you have a big block of text that you want to look for words in?

Comment: @TM, I have a big block of text from a WYSIWYG editor (html) set to a varialbe=lookHere, I want to iterate through lookHere to find SPANS with class="foods"

Comment: Good question, would be very useful.

Comment: Yep, totally misread that. What are you hoping to do with these strings that you find?

Comment: Well I have the rest of that programmed, but basically I'll be turning them into a JSON string using the SPANS, "id" and "text-in-between-the-span-tag" and posting to the server to be inserted into the db.

Comment: JQUERY's .each is amazing but I need to find a way to use it by accessing the HTML set to a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>You want $.each(), which can go over anything, not just a jQuery object. Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/</del>

Okay, now I understand. What you seem to want will require becoming pretty cozy with [javascript string methods and properties](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html#methprop), especially [split()](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html#split), and [manipulating arrays](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays).

Comment: That will find SPANS with class="foods" ? I'm not seeing how?

Comment: I don't think so, I think he wants to run the CSS selector engine against a string in a variable (if I'm reading the OP correctly), and THEN be able to to iterate the results.

Answer (score 4):

```
var html = "...";
```

Assuming `text` contains the entire html from your wysiwyg editor, these will work. Basically this parses the HTML, constructs the DOM so we can run selectors on it.

```
var nodes = $(html);
$("span.foods", nodes).each(..);
```

Or equivalently

```
$("span.foods", $(html));
```

Comment: +1, this is better than my suggestion of inserting it into the page.

Comment: Won't this leak DOM elements? They don't go away just because the collection pointing to them does.

Comment: This is just a snippet. If this were in a global scope, then yes - `var nodes = $(html);` will keep the object around until the page unloads or we do something about it. From within a function, as long as no circular references are being created, the object will be reclaimed whenever the garbage collector runs after `each()` is done with it.

Comment: Nevermind, I thought that the `document` held references to `createElement`ed nodes. I was wrong.